# Deploying assemblies through .dwp or .webpart files

Tags: iis, sharepoint

I have an assembly which I need to GAC on a SharePoint machine I cannot access remotely. I am however able to deploy `.dwp` or `.webpart` files to the website.

There is already a entry in the SafeControls list for the assembly in the `web.config`.

Would I be able to deploy the assembly through a web part?

Comment: If this is allowed, I think it would be a huge security risk. You should be deploying DLLs to the GAC using a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For deploying files in assembly you no need to create webpart. You can do it by creating a simple WSP.